# Deploy Spring MVC 3 Application to tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, deployment

I have a Spring MVC 3 Web Application which I an run without any issue in tomcat when running ti from within netbeans. In netbeans you just have to click on "Run" and a Web Application project is automatically deployed to bundled tomcat installation.

Howver now I'm trying to run the same app outside of netbeans. I put the war file into tomcats webapp directory and log says it is deploying it. However my application (= the spring context) is never loaded.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>My Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyWebApp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/ApplicationContext.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyWebApp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/jsp/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

There is no error message. The Spring Context is just not loaded.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG. I browsed to the wrong page. URL is case-sensitive so MyWebApp/index will work but myWebApp/index not.